# Why there is a collabora.list on my raspbian wheezy source repo?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy, apt, raspbian-jessie, source.list

Why there are more sources repos on my raspbian wheezy?

They are `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/collabora.list`.

For what are they needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collabora has improved software for the foundation under contract. They implemented Hardware acceleration inside Webkit (for Ephiphany) and did work on a Wayland desktop called [Maynard](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/preview-the-upcoming-maynard-desktop/).

It makes sense that they run an extra repository with the improved versions.

Sources :

- http://raspberrypi.collabora.co.uk/maynard.html
- http://blog.barisione.org/2014-09/rpi-browser/

Comment: And do you know why they don't have jessie repo?

Answer (score 3):

As the directory would suggest, those are the list of "sources" from which `apt-get` will pull applications from. `etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` lists the official repos, and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/collabora.list` appears to be an official mirror.

Comment: I think I collabora is just libre office stuff.  If you look inside the file, you should find an http address that you can browse to find out what's in the repo.

Comment: @goldilocks: I don't have that file, but from a quick google search listed it as an official mirror. That would make sense though since I don't have LibreOffice installed.

Comment: @Jacobm001: I have done a wheezy to jessie upgrade and the collabora source breaks with jessie.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the individual files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files that Jacobm001 refers to, the "master" file in `/etc/apt/sources.list` is also used - it pre-dates the "individual repository file in a sub-directory" format that Debian (and thus Raspbian) now uses, and will probably have at least a reference to a `mirrordirector.raspbian.org` source which actually redirects requests to a local mirror for you.